# .htaccess process subdomain with domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have directory structure as follows:

```
/var/www/example/
├── example.com
│   └── index.php
└── sub.example.com
    └── .htaccess
```

`.htaccess` files content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /var/www/example/example.com/index.php
```

What I am trying to achieve is whenever user visits subdomain `sub.example.com` request will be processed by `index.php` of main domain without browser redirecting to `example.com`, but instead it says `404 Not Found`.

I also tried using `DocumentRoot /var/www/example/example.com` but it lead to `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Have you tried like this? `DirectoryIndex example/example.com/index.php`

Comment: `DocumentRoot ` is only allowed in Apace server config files.

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz this lead to `403 Forbidden` error unforunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without htaccess using Symlink.

Using Server Console:

```
// All Files Symlink (Directory)
cd /var/www/example
ln -s example.com sub.example.com

// Custom Files Symlink (index.php)
cd /var/www/example/sub.example.com
ln -s "../example.com/index.php" "index.php"
```

Comment: You can also do it using PHP http://php.net/manual/tr/function.symlink.php